# How to make distinction with selection multiple objects on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We have a table like this:

```
id      date       code
-----------------------
 1      01/10/14   COO1
 2      02/10/14   C002
 3      03/10/14   C004
 1      04/10/14   C001
 2      05/10/14   C002
 3      06/10/14   C004
 3      07/10/14   C005
```

The desired output should be like this:

```
id     date       code
-----------------------
1      01/10/14   COO1
2      02/10/14   C002
3      03/10/14   C004
3      07/10/14   C005
```

I don't want to select if id and code exist before table.

It tried this basic SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM mytable
```

But this couldn't help me

How Can I do This?

Thanks For Helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used subquery which returns min(date)for each code

```
  /*CREATE TABLE tbl(
                id   int  ,
                date    varchar(10),
                code varchar(10))
INSERT INTO tbl (id  ,    date   ,    code)
 VALUES
 (1    ,    '01/10/14' ,  'COO1'),
 (2    ,    '02/10/14' ,  'C002'),
 (3    ,    '03/10/14' ,  'C004'), 
 (1    ,    '04/10/14' ,  'C001'),
 (2    ,    '05/10/14' ,  'C002'),
 (3    ,    '06/10/14' ,  'C004'),
 (3    ,    '07/10/14' ,  'C005')*/


SELECT DISTINCT id   ,
              (SELECT t.date
             from (SELECT code, min(date)   date
                  FROM tbl
                  WHERE  code =x.code
                  GROUP by code)  t) date,  
            code
FROM tbl x
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dudi Konfino.Your SQL  is right.Maybe You can explain a little bit your SQL.Also I want to count SQL Result actually.How can do this.Thanks again your effort.This is your SQL Fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33a40/1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're grouping by the id and the code:

```
SELECT   id, MIN([date]), code
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY id, code
```

Comment: This isnt about date.Its about id and code.Same Id should be with different code.But Same id with same code must be with one time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   id, MIN([date]), code
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY id, code
ORDER BY id, code
```

Comment: This isnt about date.Its about id and code.Same Id should be with different code.But Same id with same code must be with one time

Comment: You say "Same id with same code must be with one time"... I assume that means one record for a given id and code. If so, then you have to group the records by id and code and hence the clause "GROUP BY id, code"

Comment: You say "Same id with same code must be with one time"... I assume that means one record for a given id and code. If so, then you have to group the records by id and code and hence the clause "GROUP BY id, code"

You example implies that when the id and code are repeated then you want to pick the date field which is the earliest and hence we select MIN([date]). You have to use an aggregate function (such as MIN, MAX, AVG, SUM etc) when you are grouping data and the field is not part of the group by clause. It seems you want MIN. Added ORDER BY clause on the assumption that you want it sorted.